# Android: Proper way to download lots of files

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app I need to download a bunch of files. My original plan was use an individual AsyncTask for each file, so that I can notify the rest of the app when each file is downloaded. I found it testing that while this works, its seems really memory in-efficient. Is there a good way to use a single AsyncTask or maybe a Service to download the files and notify on each files complete?

Comment: Maybe just spawn another `AsyncTask` when each is done, downloading the next file in your big list.

Comment: I would try to find a solution that combines the benefits of both sequential and parallel execution of the downloads. That probably means writing a simple 'manager' that manages a queue with to-be-downloaded files and active download tasks. If you limit the number of parallel downloads to e.g. 4 (just a randomly picked number - you might want to try to optimize this empirically or even per device based on its parameters), you'll probably get the best results in terms of performance/memory ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use numerous `AsyncTask`s, since you may create the list of file names, pass it to the single `AsyncTask`, and after each file is downloaded, publish the download progress with `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()`, which is run in UI thread and can easily notify other activities in your application.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, String, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress(urls[i].toString());
        }
        return 0;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // notify whomever you like with url from progress[0]
        // this is run on UI thread
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        // do something else
        // this is also run on UI thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A remote service would work, but I think it is the wrong approach since you have just a limited functionality for it.

I would use AsyncTask, but have it called by a method.

When you are finished in the AsyncTask then call the method again that will create a new AsyncTask after removing the item in the list, or updating some counter.

Remember that an AsyncTask cannot be reused, so it needs to be created fresh each time.

Answer (score 0):

From memory and network standpoint you would be better off using just one AsyncTask (or a Java thread) and download all files one by one. This greatly improves device's responsiveness and also consumes a little of memory.
In case you can control server side, I would also suggest you zip smaller files to one archive (my project also downloads a lot of files via HTTP) and it shows great improvement of speed if files are combined into archives with size of about 2-4 MB and downloaded.
In case you are downloading using just TCP/IP connection, it will not matter how big are files if you will not reestablish connection every time.
But again for HTTP the biggest time waster is usually connection establishment.