# how download several pdf files from one after another

Tags: java, android

I need to download the several pdf files from urls.I have several urls.I need to download them one after another.So what approach should i take?
How to identity whether one pdf is finished the download?

Comment: possible duplicate of [need to display in my android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050631/need-to-display-in-my-android-app)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Proper way to download lots of files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661443/android-proper-way-to-download-lots-of-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can use download managers available in android to download more files sequentially.

I recommend [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.adm). It works like charm for me.

Comment: actually i am developing application which shows pdf files in a viewpager.So when the user swipe it goes to next page and then start pdf file downloading and show it.There are around 40 pdf files which contain only one page.So how to do this?

Comment: Is it like with one click its gonna push all 40 pdf for download?

Comment: no.initially it download first page.Then when swipe it must download that page and show.

Comment: So you are trying to preload the next page in advance ?

Comment: no,when the swipe happens it must start the downloads.

Comment: Then jus pass the intent. Whichever application that can handle pdf ll be shown and user can choose just to view it in a pdf reader or can download.

Comment: is it good to use queue in java?